# Weird Blurry effect on VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

i have a weird problem with VSC, the text and icons looks like blurry sometimes, for the effect dissapear i have to mouse over the element!

[image: Blurry]
[image: Normal]
[image: Blurry]
[image: Normal]

Is anyone have a solution for this problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: their is no difference in the images

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does VS Code give a chip-like / distorted display when I hover over it with my mouse?](/q/72962855)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by resetting the Nvidia 3D settings to default.